# Request for code review: does such XmlSerializer factory have any drawbacks?

Tags: .net, multithreading, xml-serialization

People tend to recommend to cache **XmlSerializer** instances. Is this still actual? (if *no*, when has it become so?).

Also I came up with the following code and ask to review it.

- Does it have any drawbacks?
- Will it use many threads\cores for different types?
- How can I improve it?

The code:

```
public static class SerializerFactory<T>
{
    public static readonly XmlSerializer Serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
}
```

and usage:

```
var obj = (T)XmlSerializerFactory<T>.Serializer.Deserialize(input);
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163491.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the `XmlSerializer(Type)` or `XmlSerializer(Type,String)` constructors then the serialization assembly will be cached so there is very little overhead in creating a new serializer instance ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx)).

So as your factory would use this constructor, there's no real point to it. You may as well just use the constructor directly.

Comment: As I know XmlSerializer(Type, new XmlRoot(name)) has memory leak.  That's why it should be cached 2 times. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163491.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend this instead:

```
public static class SerializerFactory<T>
{
    static readonly XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    public static XmlSerializer 
    { 
        get { return serializer; }
    }
}
```

Even when you have `static readonly` fields it is best to use properties to access them.

Comment: Any particular reason why? My opinion: more code --> worse code.